# Adaptive LMS Algorithm MATLAB

Tags: matlab, adaptive-filters, least-squares

I'm having some trouble implementing my LMS Adaptive Filter in MATLAB to separate wideband and narrowband signals from a voice signal.

I'm using a delayed version of my input as a reference as well as the error term.

```
step = 0.01;
w = zeros(1, N); 
xDelayed = [zeros(1, 100) x']'; % delaying input

for n=1:length(x)
    e = x(n) - w(1)*xDelayed(n);
    w = w - step*e*xDelayed(n); 
end
```

It's essentially an implementation of this

$$w(n+1) = w(n) - \alpha e(n) x(n)$$

For some reason, my entire w (N long) vector is all the same value. 
UPDATE:

```
M = 5;
N = length(sound)
w = zeros(M, N);
STEP_SIZE = 0.01;
d = sound;
x = sound_delayed(1:N);

for i=(M+1):N
   e(i) = d(i) -  x((i-(M)+1):i)*w(:,i);
   w(:,i+1) = w(:,i) + mu * e(i) * x((i-(M)+1):i)';
end
for i=(M+1):N
    yd(i) = x((i-(M)+1):i)*w(:,i);  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your code. First, it looks like you're confusing iteration and vector indices. The computation of `e` should use *all* values of the current (delayed) data vector, filtered with the current filter coefficients. In the update equation, you subtract a scalar from a vector, which is not what you want. Again you should be using all values of the current data vector (the length of which must equal the chosen filter length).

Take a look at the Matlab code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26593385) (the second one in the EDIT-part). I haven't run it but it looks like it deals correctly with the vectors in the update loop.

Comment: I've updated my code above to adjust the error calculation. Is that correct? Also for the filter update equation, w is a vector defined from before so when I do a calculation with it, it should also return a vector back not a scalar?

Comment: @AlfroJang80: Doesn't your code produce an error? How can you multiply `w` and `xDelayed` if they have different lengths?

Comment: My apologies. I could select only the first N=length(x) values of xDelayed. Would that be a correct way of doing it. I'm sorry if there are some stupid questions, I've just gotten very confused with this.

Comment: @AlfroJang80: yes, you must use the most recent $N$ values of the (delayed) data vector.

Comment: Does that mean I need to sort of reverse my xDelayed? Like I would do xDelayed(end:N)? (not sure if that's correct syntax) But then surely I could just use x itself. I mean my delay is just adding 100 zeros to the start.

Comment: @AlfroJang80: For comuting the error, you need to implement a filtering operation. It doesn't matter if you reverse `x` or `w`. Usually, `w` contains the filter coefficients in reverse order.

Comment: I see. I've adjusted my code up there.

Comment: @AlfroJang80: I've added a link to my answer where you can find an example code. I hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. One last thing, sorry, I've adjusted my code to fit into that to test it it out (updated above). I'm getting an error on the error calculation line about matrix multiplication due to size differences. I haven't done anything to it.

Comment: @AlfroJang80: Just check the sizes of the vectors. They need to have the same lengths, and the first one must be a row, and the second one a column, in order to get a scalar value as the result.

Comment: Ah fantastic. I just did the ' to the x matrix. It's working now, although my result actually sounds worse than the original.

Comment: @AlfroJang80: That will be the next part of the journey ... :)

Comment: Ah. Thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate. I'm gonna start playing around with the step size. I'm pretty sure that's very important.